# Using variable in KSH function

Tags: scripting, ksh, function

I tried to have a switch if either an option is set or not

```
         while getopts "s:u:d:e:ch" _OPTION; do
         case $_OPTION in
         ...
         c)
                 isCSet="Y"
```

then I'm calling my function :

```
myFunction $isCSet
```

then in my function I'm doing :

`echo $1` but I don't have anything in.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you show the exact code you're runnning? And did you try to execute it in verbose mode ( `set -x` )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing to initialize `isCSet`, eg:

```
isCSet=N    
while getopts s:u:d:e:ch _OPTION; do
   case $_OPTION in
   ...
   c)
      isCSet=Y;;
   ...
```